# dlm package - Error in optim(parm, logLik, method = method, ...) : L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Tags: dlm

```
require(dlm)

start.vals = c(0,0,0)
names(start.vals) = c("lns2_obs", "lns2_alpha", "lns2_beta")

buildTVP <- function(parm, x.mat){
 parm <- exp(parm)
 return( dlmModReg(X=x.mat, dV=parm[1], dW=c(parm[2], parm[3])) )
}

TVP.mle = dlmMLE(y=k[,1], parm=start.vals, x.mat=k[,2], build=buildTVP, hessian=T)
```

in this code, `k[,1]` and `k[,2]` are 2 stocks prices. on `TVP.mle` line I got

> Error in optim(parm, logLik, method = method, ...) :    L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn' " error.

k file link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1scLaKRpSdmp-1T9qTp_5cEcBFnWKDAus

I could not find my mistake. Could you help me please?